# What is the security benefit of using PostMessage instead of a callback URL in OAuth/OIDC?

Tags: authentication, ios, openid-connect, oauth2, single-sign-on

Of all the issuers I've found, (Facebook, Twitter, Azure AD, etc) only Apple's CloudKit has the feature of "post message" as a callback (unless it's buried in the other's SDK)

Here is a screenshot of the Apple Developer Portal

[image]

**Question**

- What is the benefit of using the PostMessage API over a 30x redirect?
- Do the other STS vendors offer this (AzureAD, Facebook, Twitter, Ping, ADFS...)

Answer (score 3):

**With the redirect response mode** there are more opportunities for the access token to be leaked and it could be said that there's more responsibilities for the client application in order to do it right.

One of the consequences of using the redirect is that the access token will be accessible in the browser address bar, which can expose it to the resource owner (end-user) and although not a direct concern it can allow the end-user to do something insecure like bookmarking the URL or copy/pasting elsewhere. **The client application should clear the response in the fragment as soon as it's processed to mitigate against this**.

There's also the concern of the URL containing the access token being kept in browser history or leaked through the `Referer` header.

---

**With the web message response mode** the access token is never included as part of an URL and/or shown to the end-user so this ends up with better security characteristics.

---

In relation to support, I can speak from the [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) perspective as I currently work there. There have been a few mentions about the possibility of implementing that mode, however, nothing very concrete.

It's also fair to say that, even for SPA's, with a bit of server-side collaboration you can have something with the same characteristics of the web message response mode by using the `form_post` response mode. The `postMessage` would be done by your JS code instead of JS code owned by the authorization server.

This response mode is indeed supported by Auth0 ([see note on form post usage](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/application/web-app-sso#authentication-flow)) and given it's a final [specification](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html) it possibly also has more widespread support than the web message.